# Cannot Install gem ffi - Windows 7 64bit

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I am new to learning Cucumber/Ruby.

I have tried to install the gem 'ffi' however when I do so from the console I get the following message:

> Error installing ffi:
>       The last version of ffi (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems
>       nstalling it with `gem install ffi -v 1.9.18`
>       ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version 2.5.0.

Comment: Looks like you need to install an older version of Ruby

Comment: They haven't updated to support Ruby 2.5 yet - https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/598 - though there are ways to force it

Answer (score 5):

After a long research I finally found an answer that worked for me :)

```
gem install ffi -f
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open pull request](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/pull/599) to update `ffi` for Ruby 2.5. You will need to wait for this update, roll back to ruby Ruby <= 2.4.x, or try to install the branch from that pull request.